# get information from database via ajax and show in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

I have two input element in html fill
the first input for write user id
the second input just readonly for user name from data base

when i write user id in first input,i use ajax to fetch column of user_name via user_id from database and put in placeholder of input element in html

My html code is

```
<input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" placeholder="Write user ID"/>
<input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name"placeholder="" readonly />
```

My java script code is

```
$(document).on('blur','#user_id',function(){
    var id_n = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax_load_user_name.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'id='+id_n,
        success: function(data){
            if(data != ''){
// 
    // 1- here how to fetch result and put in placeholder or value of input element
// 2- all time is not fetch result
                    $('#user_name').html(data);
                }else{
                    $('#show').text('error fetch') ;// this is just for div show error
                }
            }
        });
      });
```

My php Code

```
<?php
include "../include_db/db.php";

    $id_post = intval($_POST['id']);
    $out_put = '';
    GLOBAL $tf_handle;


        $sql = mysqli_query($tf_handle,"SELECT `user_name` FROM `users` 
                      WHERE `user_id` = '.$id_post.' ");

    $out_put = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);

    echo $out_put;
?>
```

All time i try to fetch result i can't 
I don't know where is mistake

wonder full for every one

**UPDATE 1 in php file**

```
<?php
include "../include_db/db.php";

    if(!isset($_POST['id']))
        return false;

    $id_post = intval($_POST['id']);
    $out_put = '';
    GLOBAL $tf_handle;

    $sql = mysqli_query($tf_handle,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = '.$id_post.' ");

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql) ){
        $name = $rows['user_name'];
        $out_put .= '<input type="text" name="order_recive_name" id="order_recive_name" class="form-control input-sm"
    placeholder="'.$name.'"  readonly />';
    }


    echo $out_put;
?>
```

Comment: Is the AJAX being fired / are you getting a response from the PHP? Also, there is a massive SQLinjection vulnerability in this code, you may want to fix it before putting this anywhere near a production environment.

Comment: yes but all response is empty from php, I sure from the sql query is good . also what i will need to fix before putting in any where , are you main isset($_post['']) in php or other thing ?

Comment: "All time i try to fetch result i can't" You can't? Get any errors? Get no results? What does your browser console say?

Comment: Along with the injection, you have concatenation that is not necessary so that will cause your query to not find the record so let's say your `$id_post = 20;`, then with:  `"SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '.$id_post.' "` you're actually querying:  `"SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_id = '.20.' "` (notice the two `.` at the front and back).

Comment: see to update of php file, if I use init of **$out_put** via $out_put = $id_post, the code not go to while loop and print $id_post.  the name of table name and name of column in database is write i sure from this query in other place

Comment: To fix the query (and probably the output) just correctly bind parameters.

Comment: yes thank you very much  the mistake is two dot in query, i copy past from other page and change var & adding dot ........** thank to all**